# rails ancestry nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tree, nested-forms, nested-sets

I've just started using Ancestry instead of awesome_nested_set and I would like to create a nested form so that I can create a parent account and many children accounts all in the one form. The problem seems to be that Ancestry doesn't allow you to create a child for a new parent.

In awesome_nested_set I could do this in the rails console

```
a = Account.new
a.children.build
```

When I type a.children I can see that new child in there even though my account parent hasn't been created yet.  This allowed me to display a form with the parent account and a few blank children, then on submit I would just ignore any blank children and create the whole lot.

If I try and do the same using ancestry I get the following error:

```
a=Account.new
a.children
Ancestry::AncestryException: No child ancestry for new record. Save record before performing tree operations.
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ancestry-1.2.4/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb:62:in `child_ancestry'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ancestry-1.2.4/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb:132:in `child_conditions'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ancestry-1.2.4/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb:136:in `children'
    from (irb):8
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Is this a limitation of ancestry?
I there a different way in which I could create a nested form using ancestry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ran into the same problem today - I believe it to be a [limitation of ancestry](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ajC9gA2AGxygJ%3arubydoc.info/github/stefankroes/ancestry/master/Ancestry/InstanceMethods+%22No+child+ancestry+for+new+record.%22&hl=en&gl=nz&strip=1), looking at the code (it raises this error `if new_record?`).

While it's not ideal, at the moment I'm using `children.create` instead of `children.build`.

Comment: Yes it's not ideal. Due to this problem and also the fact that it doesn't play nicely with thinking-sphinx and pagination over a multi-dimensional hash looks impossible I'm returning to awesome-nested-set. I do like the cleanness of ancestry and it would be good for simple things, but it's not for my current project.

Comment: I've run into the same problem trying to write tests with FactoryGirl. Sorry to zombie this question, but I thought this might be interesting to some.